# Adding Drop down to Navbar

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am having a hard time adding drop down to my Navbar without changing the CSS too much. I was trying to do it for a couple of hours now, and I failed.

When I change the HTMl or add block in CSS the navbar is broken, could you please guide me with this, what would be the best or simple way just to add a slide bar when hover over the nabar?

```css
html, body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.container {
  max-width: 940px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 5px;
}

.jumbotron {
  background: url(http://www.mathiasgerlach.com/data/files/2013/09/Vaillant_02.jpg) center;
  background-size: cover;
  height: 300px;
}

.header {
  background-color: #333;
}

.nav {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 20px 0;
  letter-spacing: 1.6px;
}

.nav li {
  transition: 0.4s;
  color: #fff;
  display: inline;
  font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: 12px;
  margin-right: 25px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.nav li:hover {
  background-color: #ffffff;
  color: #333;
  font-weight: 900;
  padding: 24px 10px;
  font-size: 12px;
  cursor: pointer;


}

.activeBold {
  font-weight: bold;
}

.main {
  position: relative;
  top: 180px;
  text-align: center;
}

.main h1 {
  color: #333;
  font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: 70px;
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-bottom: 80px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.btn-main {
  background-color: #333;
  color: #fff;
  font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: 18px;
  letter-spacing: 1.3px;
  padding: 16px 40px;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.btn-second {
  border: 1px solid #333;
  color: #000;
  font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: 10px;
  letter-spacing: 1.3px;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;  
  display: inline-block;
  margin-bottom: 20px;      
}

.supporting {
  padding-top: 80px;
  padding-bottom: 100px;
}

.supporting .col {
  float: left;
  width: 33%;
  font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
}

.supporting img {
  height: 32px;
}

.supporting h2 {
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: 23px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.supporting p {
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 20px;
  padding: 0 50px;
  margin-bottom: 40px;
}

.clearfix {
  clear: both;
}

.footer {
  background-color: #333;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 30px 0;
}

.footer p {
  font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 11px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway:400, 600" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="stylesheet.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script type='text/javascript' src='script.js'></script>
    <script src="jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
    <title>Smart-Home</title>
  </head>
<body>

  <div class="header">
    <div class="container">
      <ul class="nav">
        <li>O firmie</li>
        <li>Produkty</li>
        <li>Nasi partnerzy</li>
        <li>Kontakt</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="jumbotron">
    <div class="container">  
      <div class="main">
        <h1>Smart Home</h1>
        <a class="btn-main" href="#">ZŁÓŻ ZAMÓWIENIE</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>


  <div class="supporting">
    <div class="container">

      <div class="col">
        <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQY1_mc6oM6PXGx6CW5qKsq_fmJqUjlqf_l37QSqQOTK5CLSv78">
        <h2>Realizacje</h2>
        <p> Specjalizujemy się w Opis opis Opis opis  Opis opis  Opis opis Opis opis   .</p>
        <a class="btn-second" href="#">dowiedz się więcej</a>
      </div>

      <div class="col">
        <img src="https://www.iconexperience.com/_img/i_collection_png/512x512/plain/notebook.png">
        <h2>Oferta</h2>
        <p>Opis opis  Opis opis  Opis opis  Opis opis Opis opis  </p>
        <a class="btn-second" href="#">dowiedz się więcej</a>
      </div>

      <div class="col">
        <img src="https://www.iconexperience.com/_img/i_collection_png/256x256/plain/tools.png">
        <h2>Serwis</h2>
        <p>Opis opis  Opis opis  Opis opis  Opis opis  Opis opis </p>
        <a class="btn-second" href="#">dowiedz się więcej</a>
      </div>

    </div>
    <div class="clearfix"></div>
  </div>

  <div class="footer">
    <div class="container">
      <p>&copy; Smart home 2017</p>
    </div>
  </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What part of your code is mean to be the dropdown

Comment: I would like to have dropdown for: 

 <div class="header">
    <div class="container">
      <ul class="nav">
        <li>O firmie</li>
        <li>Produkty</li>
        <li>Nasi partnerzy</li>
        <li>Kontakt</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can follow the idea behind this.

**HTML**

```
<div class="dropdown">
  <button class="dropbtn">Dropdown</button>
  <div class="dropdown-content">
    <a href="#">Link 1</a>
    <a href="#">Link 2</a>
    <a href="#">Link 3</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
/* Dropdown Button */
.dropbtn {
    background-color: #4CAF50;
    color: white;
    padding: 16px;
    font-size: 16px;
   border: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}

/* The container <div> - needed to position the dropdown content */
.dropdown {
position: relative;
display: inline-block;
}

/* Dropdown Content (Hidden by Default) */
.dropdown-content {
display: none;
position: absolute;
background-color: #f9f9f9;
min-width: 160px;
box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
z-index: 1;
}

/* Links inside the dropdown */
.dropdown-content a {
color: black;
padding: 12px 16px;
text-decoration: none;
display: block;
}

/* Change color of dropdown links on hover */
.dropdown-content a:hover {background-color: #f1f1f1}

/* Show the dropdown menu on hover */
.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
display: block;
}

/* Change the background color of the dropdown button when the dropdown content is shown */
.dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
background-color: #3e8e41;
}
```

**Reference** [css dropdown menu](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_dropdown.asp)

Comment: Stack-overflow is for quick small solutions not for website maintenance. Please do not over assist people since this is a paid job for developers!

Comment: I am very sorry about that. Now I know.Thanks very much @mazenelzoor